# Confusion matrix not giving the whole data for Neural Network sklearn Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, neural-network, confusion-matrix

I'm just trying to get confusion matrix for my whole data set.

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
from neupy import algorithms

df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv', header=None)

df = df.rename(columns={0: 'season_at_test', 
                        1: 'age',
                        2: 'child',
                        3: 'trauma',
                        4: 'surgery',
                        5: 'fever',
                        6: 'alcohol',
                        7: 'smoking','
                       })

df['smoking'] = df['smoking'].map({'N': 1, 'O':0})

data = df.iloc[:, :-1]
target = df['diagnosis']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, target, test_size=0.2, random_state=303)


pnn = algorithms.PNN(std=10, verbose=False)

pnn.train(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = pnn.predict(X_test)

print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))

pnn = algorithms.PNN(std=10, verbose=False)

pnn.train(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = pnn.predict(X_test)

print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))

metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

And it gives me;

```
Accuracy: 0.7
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 5, 14]], dtype=int64)
```

This output. Also i need to run 2 times to work it gives me an error at the first run.
My confusion matrix should be something like the below result because i have 100 sample not 20.

```
[ 58,  30]
[ 5, 7]
```

And if i try to add something like

```
y_pred = pnn.predict(X_test)
x_pred = pnn.predict(data)

metrics.confusion_matrix(x_pred, y_test)
```

It gives me "ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [100, 20] "

How can i make this work for all of my data? I want a confusion matrix for all of my 100 samples.

Answer (score 1):

When you perform `train_test_split` on `data` which has 100 entries you split the data into two (train and test). With 20% going into the test set as defined by `test_size=0.2` so `y_test` will have 20% of `data` which equals 20 entries. This is expected behaviour.

If you want to get the confusion matrix on the entire dataset you should do:

```
y_pred = pnn.predict(data)
metrics.confusion_matrix(target, y_pred)
```

This approach is **not** recommend as it will not represent the true performance of the model on unseen data.